# How to keep Persistent state of WebApp after closing the browser using javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an application using `javascript`, it consists of 4, 5 pages. If a user closes the browser and open application again, browser should display the last state of the application including respective screen and any half-filled form.

Can you please tell me how to do it in realm of `javascript`.

Thank you.

Comment: What about using cookies?

Comment: Local storage, maybe.

Comment: http://www.whatarecookies.com/

Comment: I guess, local storage would do it. I would use is @sideroxylon and will answer my question. :-) Thanks.